# Shadow Mapping, why does my shadow change size and position when I rotate my light?

Tags: glsl, shadows, shadow-mapping, glm

I have looked far and wide for this and have not found any issue like this, so far. Basically, when my light is at a certain angle my shadows seem to be correctly positioned and scaled, yet if I rotate the light about itself, both of these things change.

It should be about that size and position but it is rotated incorrectly here.

[image: Seemingly correct shadow on teapot]

[image: Completely incorrect]

In this image, it is completely incorrect.

Now for my code.

1st, the code run on the CPU concerning the shadow map:

In the load, I create my shadow map based on the width and height of the screen.

```
shadow = shadow_map(renderer::get_screen_width(), renderer::get_screen_height());
```

And I set up my shaders, no need to show it, that bit's working. In the update method I give my shadow map the properties of the light used to create the shadow like so:

```
shadow.light_dir = normalize(spot.get_direction());
shadow.light_position = spot.get_position();
```

Then in my render method I do this:

```
renderer::set_render_target(shadow);
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
renderer::bind(shadow_eff);
for (auto &e : meshes)
{
        auto m = e.second;
        auto M = m.get_transform().get_transform_matrix();
        auto V = shadow.get_view();
        //glm::lookAt(light_position, light_position + light_dir, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
        auto P = cam.get_projection();
        auto MVP = biasMatrix * (P * V * M);
  glUniformMatrix4fv(shadow_eff.get_uniform_location("MVP"),1,GL_FALSE,value_ptr(MVP));
renderer::render(m);
}

glCullFace(GL_BACK);
//set render target back to screen
renderer::set_render_target();

//...

auto lM = m.get_transform().get_transform_matrix();
        auto lV = shadow.get_view();
        auto lP = cam.get_projection();
        auto lMVP = (lP * lV * lM);

        glUniformMatrix4fv(main_eff.get_uniform_location("lightMVP"), 1, GL_FALSE, value_ptr(lMVP));

//bind the shadow map texture
renderer::bind(shadow.buffer->get_depth(), 1);
        glUniform1i(main_eff.get_uniform_location("shadow_map"), 1);
```

It is worth noting that my bias matrix looks like this:

```
0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5,
0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5,
0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5,
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
```

Now onto the shader code:

```
void main()
{
    // **********************
    // Calculate shade factor
    // **********************
    float shade = calculate_shadow(shadow_map, light_space_pos);
    // ************************
    // Calculate view direction
    // ************************
    vec3 view_dir = normalize(eye_pos - position);
    // **************
    // Sample texture
    // **************
    vec4 tex_colour = texture(tex, tex_coord);
    // ********************
    // Calculate spot light
    // ********************
    colour = calculate_spot(spot, mat, position, normal, view_dir, tex_colour);
    // *********************
    // Scale colour by shade
    // *********************
    colour *= vec4(shade, shade, shade, 1.0);

    colour.a = 1.0;
}
```

Where calculate_shadow(...) looks like this:

```
float calculate_shadow(in sampler2D shadow_map, in vec4 light_space_pos)
{
    vec3 light_dir = normalize(spot.position - position);

    vec3 proj_coords = light_space_pos.xyz / light_space_pos.w;

    proj_coords = proj_coords * 0.5 + 0.5;

    float closest_depth = texture(shadow_map, proj_coords.xy).r;
    float current_depth = proj_coords.z;

    float bias = max(0.05 * (1.0 - dot(normal, light_dir)), 0.005);

    float shadow = current_depth - bias > closest_depth ? 0.0 : 1.0;
    return shadow;
}
```

and the most important part of the shadow vertex shader is:

```
vertex_light = (lightMVP * vec4(vertex_position, 1.0));
```

I've been thinking about this on and off for weeks, any help is appreciated. In my experience it's usually something small that I've got wrong. Thanks in advance.